# add new column in Pandas Data frame with categories

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following wine classification data:

```
country, price, colour
USA      10     white
italy    25     red
USA      75     rose
Germany  125    white
```

I have to add a new column in `pandas` based on the information below:

New column Name is `'Affordability'`:

`Cheap` if price < 50 or `expensive` if price is >50 but Price <100 or `very exp` if price >100

Comment: Would you also share what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy.select` to add an extra column with conditions:

```
import numpy as np 
condlst = [df['price_column'] < 50,
           df['price_column'] < 100,
           df['price_column'] >= 100]
choicelst = ['Cheap',
             'Expensive',
             'Very Expensive',]
df['Affordability'] = np.select(condlist, choicelst)
```

Please note:

- the number of conditions should always match the number of choices.
- conditions provided here are self excluding and will be checked in the order inserted so first it will check if the price is below 50 and if not will check if the price is below 100 and so on. This way you save the number of checks you need to do.

More to read about `np.select` [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html).